# Jenkins - Hide Views

Tags: jenkins

I'm using Jenkins and I have created some views that I would only like to be visible if someone is logged in as a specific user.  Is there anyway to hide specific views from non-logged in users or specific users?

Thanks,
Eric

Comment: Can you tell me how did you do it? Jenkins->Configure Global Security -> Access control -> Security Realm -> Jenkin's own user Database -> Authorization -> Matrix Based Security this did not hide views